# count values from array which are between values in datatable columns

Tags: c#, arrays, datatable

I am looking for a quick method to find how many times a value exists which is between 2 column values in a datatable, for example if  I had 1 row in the datatable and col 1 = 100 and col2 = 102 then my array should have 1 in for elements 100,101 & 102. I hope this is clear. The data table can have as much as 50,000 records so need the count of rows which meet this criteria. The following code works, but is realy slow. Any help would be greatly apreciated.
Thanks in advance.

```
int [] arr = new int [1200];

for(int a=0;a<arr.GetUpperBound(0);a++)
{
    arr[a] = (int)dt.Compute("Count(Col1)", a+" >= col1 And "+a+" <= col2");
};
```

Comment: You need find number of rows or number of values?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to find number of rows which have match at least one value in array, then you can try following Linq to DataSet query:

```
dt.AsEnumerable()
  .Select(r => new { Col1 = r.Field<int>("Col1"), Col2 = r.Field<int>("Col2") })
  .Where(r => arr.Any(i => r.Col1 <= i && i <= r.Col2))
  .Count();
```

This query first projects each row to anonymous objects with Col1 and Col2 values. Than it filters out result which don't have any appropriate items in array. And last step is getting count of rows.